# Scrollbar not longer showing when open a (html) popup

Tags: html, css, popup, frontend

My scrollbar isn't longer showing when opening a popup. How can I make that the scrollbar isn't going away when opening a popup.

This is without popup opened (Scrollbar shows): https://gyazo.com/c682818f10aa3dfddeaef1b20ad68ae6

This is with popup opened (Scrollbar doesn't show):
https://gyazo.com/d243cee844b7eb5b9d8197beddb1caa3

Comment: You will have to give us more information. No code = no answer.

Comment: why I am just asking for a code that shows the scrollbar in popup.

Comment: I can't magically give you a line of code to show a scrollbar without knowing your page's structure or the library that you are using.

Comment: You can try this CSS: `body {overflow-y: scroll!important;}`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me @JoostS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this CSS: `body {overflow-y: scroll!important;}`. This works quite often because it overrules the javascript that tries to hide the overflow on the body.

Note that this solution also shows the scrollbar on desktop computers when it is not needed (an empty gray gutter on the right side of your screen). That might be an unwanted side-effect.